# Failed to acquire token for client credentials for azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, token

I'm trying to deploy this application to azure web apps: https://github.com/swissbyte/clockify-nlp-bot

I have therefore adjusted my appsettings.json to contain the following values:

```
    "BlobStorage": {
    "DataConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "ContainerName": "chatbot"
},
"LuisAppId": "533fc959-0274-40ac-b8c4-XXXXXXXXX",
"LuisAPIHostName": "XXXXXXX-20-luis.cognitiveservices.azure.com",
"LuisAPIKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"KeyVaultName": "XXXXXXXXX20-keyvault",
"MicrosoftAppId": "14ec576a-f6c2-42e2-XXXX-02e5c2ae96ed",
"MicrosoftAppPassword": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"MicrosoftTenantId": "2b63482d-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-e0c3af721b85",
"MicrosoftAppType": "SingleTenant",
"ProactiveBotApiKey": "Value"
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error, as soon as I reach the following code:

File: UtilityHandler.cs:65

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(
            MessageFactory.Text(string.Format(_messageSource.HelpIntro, "\n", turnContext.Activity.ChannelId)),
            cancellationToken);
```

> Failed to acquire token for client credentials. (AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '14ec576a-XXXX-42e2-XXXX-02e5c2ae96ed' was not found in the directory 'Bot Framework'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
> Trace ID: 0e745d71-34e4-40f3-9b20-e0df14748401
> Correlation ID: c31e96c6-af34-47de-b795-b4b9d7edf9b4
> Timestamp: 2021-12-28 12:16:56Z)

One thing that I am asking myself is, whether I have to configure something special within my code to make the app work with a SingleTenant WebApp. I have added the "MicrosoftAppType" to the appsettings.json.

I have created the setup on azure using the example echo bot template from Microsoft: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot/DeploymentTemplates/template-with-preexisting-rg.json

The Echobot has worked as expected. Only when I try to deploy the new bot, I get this error message.

What I have tried already:

- Re-creating the secret and updating it.

Any suggestions are highly welcome :)
Thanks

---- Update:

I have digged more into the deepths of this problem and tried the following:

- Fetching the publish profile of the web app
- Publishing the echo bot from here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot using the correct settings (The ones mentioned above)
- Checked -> Bot is working

Now i took the exactly same publish profile and uploaded the 2nd, newer bot (https://github.com/swissbyte/clockify-nlp-bot)

- Checked the bot -> not working, still the same error
- Now i changed the authentification settings within azure to multi tenant
- Rechecked the 2nd bot and -> less errors. Now i only got the following:

> Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'

And the trace looks like this:

> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter: Information: GetTokenAsync: Acquired token using ADAL in 2775.
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter: Information: GetTokenAsync: Acquired token using ADAL in 2784.
> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Bot.Supports.AdapterWithErrorHandler.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0'

Way better than before, The app is able to fetch the token due to the less strict auth policy. But the main question is, where is the difference between those two apps? Why does the 2nd bot have problems while the 1st works with exactly the same settings?

To dig more deep into this problem i tried the following:

1st bot answers to messages like this:
Receives the post here:

```
 [HttpPost, HttpGet]
    public async Task PostAsync()
    {
        // Delegate the processing of the HTTP POST to the adapter.
        // The adapter will invoke the bot.
        await Adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, Bot);
    }
```

And answers right after here:

```
        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var replyText = $"Echo CI/CD2: {turnContext.Activity.Text}";
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(replyText, replyText), cancellationToken);
    }
```

Now the 2nd bot looks like this: (BotHandler.cs)

```
        [Route("api/messages")]
    [HttpPost]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task PostAsync()
    {
        await _adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, _bot);
    }
```

And then: (Bot.cs)

```
        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {            
        var userProfile =
            await StaticUserProfileHelper.GetUserProfileAsync(_userState, turnContext, cancellationToken);
        userProfile.ConversationReference = turnContext.Activity.GetConversationReference();
        userProfile.LastConversationUpdate = _dateTimeProvider.DateTimeUtcNow();
        
        if (await _botHandlerChain.Handle(turnContext, cancellationToken, userProfile)) return;
        
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(_messageSource.MessageUnhandled), cancellationToken);
    }
```

I then thought to narrow down the problem, i turn the 2nd bot into an echo bot as well:

```
        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
    
        var replyText = $"Echo BOT2: {turnContext.Activity.Text}";
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(replyText, replyText), cancellationToken);

    }
```

But the problem persists!
There must be a difference somewhere within the code during the setup.

Any help is welcome!